# Do gyroscopes show peculiar behavior during eclipses?

Tags: gyroscopes

I'm curious about pendulums and their behavior during a solar eclipse.  I also wonder about gyroscopes and if their behavior during stellar events has been observed.  I wonder about the both of them, and of their relationships to each other.  I wonder about Mobius loops and gyroscopes; what if a gyroscope was a Mobius loop in rotation, would it precess in a traditional manner?  What if you lined the outer rim of a gyroscope with a plurality of strong magnets, all spinning the same way outwards?  What would happen next?

I wonder endlessly.

Comment: One question per question, please!

Comment: Here are some great articles on the effects of tides on precision pendulums. http://leapsecond.com/hsn2006/ (Tides are strong during eclipses). "This effect is so small, however, that only the very best, laboratory-grade, vacuum-sealed pendulum clocks can "see" the effect."

Answer (score 1):

No. We use gyroscopes to control the attitude of spacecraft. A spacecraft in low Earth orbit goes into eclipse about every 90 minutes. There is no observed effect.